# Python how to extend `str` and overload its constructor?

Tags: python, string, class, python-2.7, overloading

I have an sequence of characters, a string if you will, but I want to store metadata about the origin of the string. Additionally I want to provide a simplified constructor.

I've tried extending the `str` class in as many ways as Google would resolve for me. I gave up when I came to this;

```
class WcStr(str):
    """wc value and string flags"""

    FLAG_NIBBLES = 8 # Four Bytes

    def __init__(self, value, flags):
        super(WcStr, self).__init__()
        self.value = value
        self.flags = flags

    @classmethod
    def new_nibbles(cls, nibbles, flag_nibbles=None):
        if flag_nibbles is None:
            flag_nibbles = cls.FLAG_NIBBLES

        return cls(
            nibbles[flag_nibbles+1:],
            nibbles[:flag_nibbles]
        )
```

When I comment-out both parameters to `@classmethod`'s cls() call it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Pretty typical, wrong number of args error,

With a two more arguments (eg as shown in the example code):

```
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

I've tried changing the `__init__`'s args, the `super().__init__`'s args, neither seem to make ant change.

With only one argument passed to `cls(...)` call, as the str class's error asks, I get this:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

So I can't win here, whats gone wrong?

---

Ps this should be a second post but what property does str's raw string value get put into? I'd like to overload as little of the str class as I can to add this metadata into the constructor.

Comment: Python's raw string value doesn't get put into _any_ attribute. There's no "raw string"; its value just _is_ a string, and if that were in any attribute, it would have the same type as `str`.

Comment: Meanwhile, you need to read about [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__). It's one of those things they don't teach you because most types only need an initializer, not a constructor… but now you're trying to subclass an immutable type, so you _do_ need a constructor.

Comment: Finally, you're explicitly calling the super's `__init__` with no arguments. At best, that's going to give you an empty string. And since strings are immutable, it'll be empty forever. You probably don't want that, but I'm not sure what you _do_ want, from the rest of your code. (Are you sure you even wanted a `str` subclass at all, rather than just something that _owns_ a `str` and duck-styles as str-like by delegating a lot of methods to do?)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is exactly what the [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) method is for.

In Python, creating an object actually has two steps. In pseudocode:

```
value = the_class.__new__(the_class, *args, **kwargs)
if isinstance(value, the_class):
    value.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The two steps are called construction and initialization. Most types don't need anything fancy in construction, so they can just use the default `__new__` and define an `__init__` method—which is why tutorials, etc. only mention `__init__`.

But `str` objects are immutable, so the initializer can't do the usual stuff of setting up attributes and so on, because you can't set attributes on an immutable object.

So, if you want to change what the `str` actually holds, you have to override its `__new__` method, and call the super `__new__` with your modified arguments.

In this case, you don't actually want to do that… but you *do* want to make sure `str.__new__` doesn't see your extra arguments, so you *still* need to override it, just to hide those arguments from it.

---

Meanwhile, you ask:

> what property does str's raw string value get put into?

It doesn't. What would be the point? Its value is a string, so you'd have a `str` which had an attribute which was the same `str` which had an attribute which etc. ad infinitum.

Under the covers, of course, it has to be storing *something*. But that's under the covers. In particular, in CPython, the `str` class is implemented in C, and it contains, among other things, a C `char *` array of the actual bytes used to represent the string. You can't access that directly.

But, as a subclass of `str`, if you want to know your value as a string, that's just `self`. That's the whole point of being a subclass, after all.

---

So:

```
class WcStr(str):
    """wc value and string flags"""

    FLAG_NIBBLES = 8 # Four Bytes

    def __new__(cls, value, *args, **kwargs):
        # explicitly only pass value to the str constructor
        return super(WcStr, cls).__new__(cls, value)

    def __init__(self, value, flags):
        # ... and don't even call the str initializer 
        self.flags = flags
```

Of course you don't really *need* `__init__` here; you could do your initialization along with your construction in `__new__`. But if you don't intend for `flags` to be an immutable, only-set-during-construction kind of value, it makes more conceptual sense to do it the initializer, just like any normal class.

---

Meanwhile:

> I'd like to overload as little of the str class as I can

That may not do what you want. For example, `str.__add__` and `str.__getitem__` are going to return a `str`, not an instance of your subclass. If that's good, then you're done. If not, you will have to overload all of those methods and change them to wrap up the return value with the appropriate metadata. (You can do this programmatically, either by generating wrappers at class definition time, or by using a `__getattr__` method that generates wrappers on the fly.)

---

One last thing to consider: the `str` constructor doesn't take exactly one argument.

It can take 0:

```
str() == ''
```

And, while this isn't relevant in Python 2, in Python 3 it can take 2:

```
str(b'abc', 'utf-8') == 'abc'
```

Plus, even when it takes 1 argument, it obviously doesn't have to be a string:

```
str(123) == '123'
```

So… are you sure this is the interface you want? Maybe you'd be better off creating an object that *owns* a string (in `self.value`), and just using it explicitly. Or even using it implicitly, duck-typing as a `str` by just delegating most or all of the `str` methods to `self.value`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `__init__` try new:

```
def __new__(cls, value, flags):    
    obj = str.__new__(cls, value)
    obj.flags = flags
    return obj
```